# Can you add a validation to a switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I know this might be a simple question but how can I add validation to this switch statement. I want that if the user inputs a different number than 1,2 or 3 an error message will be displayed.

```
        Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        Console.WriteLine("    1. Create Account      ");
        Console.WriteLine("    2.     Login           ");
        Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");

        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();



        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.Clear();
                cl_class.CreateAccount();
                DisplayMenu();
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.Clear();
                Login();
                DisplayMenu();
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `default` keyword.
Use it after your last `case` (order doesn't *technically* matter, per the documentation at the link below, but you'd have a hard time convincing me to *not* put it last - it's just common practice).

```
switch (userChoice)
{
    case "1":
        Console.Clear();
        cl_class.CreateAccount();
        DisplayMenu();
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;
    case "2":
        Console.Clear();
        Login();
        DisplayMenu();
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;
    default:
        //Display error stuff
}
```

I left out a `case` for 3, since you did not include one in your example. If you want default to not catch "3", obviously just add that as a new `case` above the default.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-default-case

Comment: Glad I could help, @AndréColeiro!